# Cassandra template is updating the particular integer column of cassandra table, but in DB its not reflecting the updated value

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, spring-kafka

In my spring Kafka consumer we are trying to update a Cassandra table integer column, and from the application logs I can see everything gone fine, but when I check the Cassandra table the values are not updated. 
Below is the Cassandra template I am using to update my record column.

```
public boolean updaetCassandraTable(String primaryKey1, String primaryKey2, String primaryKey3,
            String column_to_update1, String column_to_update2){

        Update update = QueryBuilder.update("Table_to_update");
        update.where(eq("primaryKey1", primaryKey1))
                .and(eq("primaryKey2", primaryKey2))
                .and(eq("primaryKey3", primaryKey3))                
                .with(set("column_to_update1", column_to_update1))
                .and(set("column_to_update2", column_to_update2));              

        return cassandraTemplate.getCqlOperations().execute(update);
    }
```

Also, if I am bringing down the consumer and let the messages get piled up in topic and after that if i restart the consumer then all the piled up messages are getting processed all fine. Issue is happening only when the message is being consumed and processed instantly.

May be some time difference in servers is casing this or what? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes time difference might cause this issue. Sync your time between client and Cassandra.

Comment: @Nama, sorry for the late reply. You were correct, that was exactly the issue ! for some reason client system time was getting delayed and that was causing the issue. anyways thanks for the response.